# :active default red?

Tags: css

at http://www.droppoint.cz/system/objednej.php when you click the cart icon, on active the border turns red. By default the right border is slightly blue too, which shouldn't be either.

Do you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove these two effects i.e.
1.Red color on active and
2.Default blue color from right border.

Then I found that `box-shadow` is the problem here so remove these properties from your class.

These are the classes

```
#obj #cart #icon:active 
{
   /*box-shadow: -1px 0px 4px 0px inset;*/
}

#obj #cart #icon
{
 /* box-shadow: -1px 0px 5px -2px inset; */
}
```

This will remove them. Hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: i didnt spicify color for the shadow, I added #000, now works fine. Thanks